# Find the number of items that completed a process more than once

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

| Contact | Step |
| --- | --- |
| Jerry | registration |
| Mike | registration |
| Jerry | complete |
| Karl | registration |
| Richard | registration |
| Richard | complete |
| Jerry | registration |
| Jerry | complete |
| Mike | complete |
| Matthew | registration |
| Matthew | complete |
| Richard | registration |
| Richard | complete |
| Anna | registration |
| Anna | complete |
| Richard | registration |
| Karl | complete |
| Richard | complete |
| Anna | registration |
| Anna | complete |

The table above is a depiction of a software registration process. Registration indicates that the contact is in the registration process and complete mena that they have completed it.

I'd like to know the number of contacts that completed the registration more than once and how many times they completed it.

So the queried results should look like this:

| Contact | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Jerry | 2 |
| Anna | 2 |
| Richard | 3 |

How is this achievable with SQL/Postgresql. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `GROUP BY` along with `HAVING`

```
SELECT
T.Contact,
COUNT(*) 
 FROM
YOUR_TABLE T 
WHERE T.step='complete'
GROUP BY T.Contact
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```